# Cómo puedo restar un vector R

Tags: r

Tengo un vector, y necesito restar todos los valores que hay dentro de él, sin embargo no sé que función utilizar.

(Se que la función Sum() me permite sumarlos, necesito saber si hay una función como esa, pero con la resta

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!. ¿Podrías darnos el código?, para tener más facilidad en ayudarte.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por responder. No tengo un código como tal, te comento el ejercicio que tengo que hacer. Me mandaron a crear una matriz de 100x8, con valores aleatorios, y luego sumar la resta de los números positivos, con el promedio de todos los datos, luego tengo que sumar la adición de los números negativos, con el mismo promedio. Sé cómo sumar la adición, puesto que es usar la función "sum()", pero me falta hacer la resta

Comment: Hubieras indicado eso en tu pregunta, pero espero que mi respuesta te pueda ayudar en lo que solicitas, también se pueden implementar en matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Espero te ayude el ejemplo que he logrado investigar. Empecemos teniendo 2 vectores, declarados de la siguiente forma:

```
Vector_1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
Vector_2 <- c(4, 5, 6)
```

Ahora, para comenzar a hacer las operaciones matemáticas, es muy importante destacar que las operaciones matemáticas se producen entre los valores situados en una misma posición dentro de los vectores respectivos. Es decir, el primer elemento del Vector_1 (1) se relaciona con el primer elemento del Vector_2 (4). Me explico, si en caso fuese una suma, el resultado de esta primer elemento sería 5. Este proceso se repite sucesivamente con el resto de los elementos de los vectores.

```
Vector_1 + Vector_2 # suma de los dos vectores
[1] 5 7 9
Vector_1 - Vector_2 # resta de los dos vectores
[1] -3 -3 -3
Vector_1 / Vector_2 # división de los dos vectores
[1] 0.25 0.40 0.50
Vector_1 * Vector_2 # multiplicación de los dos vectores
[1]  4 10 18
```

Y por último, podemos guardar el resultado de estas operaciones matemáticas creando nuevos objetos, que llamaremos suma_vect, resta_vect, div_vect y multip_vect, o como usted desee llamarles. Estos objetos se corresponden con la suma, la resta, la división y la multiplicación de vectores, respectivamente.

```
suma_vect   <- Vector_1 + Vector_2 # suma de los dos vectores
resta_vect  <- Vector_1 - Vector_2 # resta de los dos vectores
div_vect    <- Vector_1 / Vector_2 # división de los dos vectores
multip_vect <- Vector_1 * Vector_2 # multiplicación de los dos vectores
# Vemos los resultados
suma_vect
[1] 5 7 9
resta_vect
[1] -3 -3 -3
div_vect
[1] 0.25 0.40 0.50
multip_vect
[1]  4 10 18
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Si lo que deseas es restar todos los elementos de un vector, la forma más rápida es la siguiente:

```
# Definamos el vector
  v <- c(13,2,53,15,9)
# Resta de todos los valores
  sum(-v)
```

Piensa que restar todos los valores es lo mismo que sumar los valores del vector cambiado de signo, de ahí la fórmula.